# Responding to an AJAX call with only Success or Failure?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC Ajax form, and I'm only using it to perform some basic operations.

I'm coding in C#, HTML, Razor, and jQuery.

What I'd like to do is only respond with one of two possibilities, success or failure.

With what do I respond to the AJAX call to specify either success or failure? Status codes? I can't seem to find any documentation on this for some reason.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: so what's your programming problem that you want us to answer? there is no mention of which language you're using, what code you already have, and it seems like you're confusing "ajax" with what a server does (ajax calls are made by the browser, to a server. status codes is what you get back from a server)

Comment: I would simply return the json `{"success":true}` or `{"success":false}`.

Comment: 'AJAX' is the name for synchronous JavaScript server-calls. It's not language-independent, it's literally just JavaScript (that's the 'J' in the acronym =)

Comment: the idea behind an AJAX approach isn't specific to JavaScript, but when you use the term AJAX, you're understood to be specifically referring to getting data from a server using JavaScript calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simply return the json `{"success":true}` or `{"success":false}`.

This is plain simple and should do it's job.

Comment: with an extra note that you may need the server to also say it's response ContentType is "application/json".